# TS complaining about undefine props even its inside an if condition

Tags: typescript

why TS is complaining that `'data.st' is possibly 'undefined'.` in this code, even its inside the if condition.

```
interface Data {
  st?: number;
}

let events = [{id: 1, st: 123}, {id: 2, st: 465}];

function test(data: Data) {
  if (data.st) {
    events = events.filter(
      (ce) => ce.st >= data.st, // 'data.st' is possibly 'undefined'.
    );
  }
}
```

here is the [playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5AZzAH4AuZEAVwFsAjaAblwF9dcAbCMZCANwjhCyALzIA2tmAATCgEYANETDyATAGYWSqbOSqlxCgBYAbAFYWAXWa4YVEAjDAA9iGSRiACmkY4FdJgAlDj4yMAwyN6%20AHTEwXgEBPyCYMJiyULRMMAckFCeoYmRSMEiAHzISLE8ZWI%20mNUKhciBzARsLEA)

Comment: Just add a `const st = data.st;` before the filter call and compare to `st` instead of `data.st`.

Comment: wow... it worked. But why?

Comment: It seems to be a hard problem to solve. It's difficult for the TypeScript compiler to figure out if `data` is being changed somewhere in the callback function. A long thread about "not enough type-narrowing" versus "too much type-narrowing" [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `ref` to the `data` that you want to use and check that.

Something similar to this:

```
function test(data: Data) {
  const st = data.st;

  if (st) {
    events = events.filter(
      (ce) => ce.st >= st
    );
  }
}
```

They main reason why this `TS` cannot narrow here is because is actually `unsound`.
You are passing a callback to `events.filter` and there is no guarantee that your callback is gonna get executed right away. There is no way (at least to my knowledge) to signal that a function will execute the callbacks provided in the same execution run. In this case we know that `Array.filter` does this, but from `TS` point of view there is no guarantee of this.

The second reason why this doesn't work is that `TS` cannot properly track all the references to `data` to figure out is some other piece of code could change `data.ts` between the time of the check and the time of the execution callback.

It can actually figure this out if you declare it as `const` and then narrow it.

The behaviour regarding callbacks can also be noticed in this case:

```
function test(data: Data) {
  let st = data.st;

  if (st) {
    events = events.filter(
      (ce) => ce.st >= st
    );
  }
}
```

You are still gonna get the same error now. The main reason is the callback call. If you check the `st` type before the callback you'll see that it got narrowed to `number`, but inside the callback it gets widened to `number | undefined`.

You can check the second example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5AZzAH4AuZEAVwFsAjaAblwF9dcAbCMZCANwjhCyALzIA2tmAATCgEYANETDyATAGYWSqbOSqlxCgBYAbAFYWAXWa4YVEAjDAA9iGSRiACmkY4FdJgAlDj4yFw8xKLIPpgAdMQ2BMAwyJ7EwXgEBMS4APS5BAB6JKEE-IJgwmLlQrEwwByQUJ6lWZ5IwSIAfMhI8TxdYsQKeQVZ4xOTRSXjgcwEbCxAA)